# use of comparison operator in return

Tags: stl

I often use standard function in cpp
`sort(A.begin(),A.end(),mycmp)`

where,

```
 bool mycmp(int a, int b)
       return (a>b);
```

to sort the vector A. But, when the question asks customized sorting then I often seem confused and take many tries to fix my compare function.Can someone explain that what exactly `return (a>b);` means; I read some posts also but still cant figure out how a>b determine the order to descending.

> posts:
>   [configure the compare function to work with std::sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558792/configure-the-compare-function-to-work-with-stdsort)

---

Answer (score 0):

You can think `cmp` as an implementation of less than operator `<`. I use `lt` other than `<` after.

To simplify the question, assume we have bubble sort:

```
typedef bool (*cmp)(int, int);

bool inc(int a, int b) { return a < b; }
bool dec(int a, int b) { return a > b; }

void bubble_sort(int a[], int n, cmp lt) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j+1<n-i; ++j) {
            if (lt(a[j+1], a[j])) swap(a[j], a[j+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

`a[j], a[j+1]` swaps only if `lt(a[j+1],a[j])` is `true`.

- if we pass `inc` as comparing function, then `lt(a[j+1],a[j])` is `true` means `a[j+1]<a[j]`, so it sorts increasingly.
- If we pass `dec` as comparing function, then `lt(a[j+1],a[j])` is `true` means `a[j+1]>a[j]`, so it sorts decreasingly.

---

You can check sgi sort implementation for more details.

1. https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html
2. https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html

Comment: Thanks @delta. in your answer can you clearify that what value will be returned by the dec function when lt(a[j+1],a[j]) is ture ? Is it 1? and if so how it helps sort to make the order decreasing .

Comment: @mouse it is `ture` or `false` according to type signature. `sort` needs you   to define how the set is ordered, if you does not provide one, it uses default `<`. `cmp` is just a function to define `<`. In `sort`, element `x` appears before `y` iff `lt(x,y)` is `true`. I think you can read some  discrete mathematics, it will help.